# Не понимаю синтаксис Groovy

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

Из документации по Gradle ясно, что для написания плагинов и тасков используется язык Groove. Как я понимаю в build.gradle android-проекта используется именно язык Groovy, но при просмотре синтаксиса Groovy я ненашел такие вот конструкции с вложениями:

```
  buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Как понимать такой синтаксис? Где здесь функция, параметры и что означают эти вложения?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/458046/

Answer (score 3):

Содержимое файлов gradle - всего лишь код на языке Groovy. Разберем приведенный вами пример:

При вызове функции в Groovy, скобки являются необязательными, если не возникает неоднозначности. Таким образом:

- `minifyEnabled false` это тоже самое что `minifyEnabled(false)`
- `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` это `proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro')`.

Точно также, `release { ... }` это вызов метода `release`, которому в качестве параметра передается замыкание (https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html), аналогично происходит при вызове `buildTypes { ... }` (эквивалентно `buildTypes({ ... })`.

Я рекомендую эту шпаргалку, чтобы разобраться получше: https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-optional-parenthesis.html